# Search-and-replace across multiple line ranges

Tags: vim

Is it possible to do something like the following in vim?

```
:1,3|7,9 s/import/new
```

What I'm trying to do is:

- Replace the word 'import' with 'new' on lines 1-3
- Do the same on lines 7-9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+multiple+ranges

Comment: `:1,3s/import/new/ | 7,9&&`

Comment: yeah, or perhaps, `%s/import/new/gc`.  Specifically, just use the confirm flag and decline changes on lines where you do not want to have the substitution.